# Vue V-For returning undefined component properties

Tags: vue.js

I normally wouldn't make a post for something which seems quite simple, but I've been playing around with this v-for in my Vue component all day now and I am still unable to find out what is wrong. The parent component has a correct property containing the array of posts which it passes onto the child component, but there are way too many child components created (the original object only contains 3 arrays), and all of those child component's properties are undefined, despite having utilized this exact v-for code elsewhere with no issue.

Here's the parent component:

```html
<template>
      <div class="user-post-section-cell-container">
        <user-post
            v-for="(post, index) of posts"
            :image-src="post.imageSrc"
            :key="index"
            :id="post.id"
            :caption="post.caption"
            :location="post.location"
            :href="post.href"
            :friend-name="post.friendName"
            :friend-img-src="post.friendImgSrc"
        >
        </user-post>
      </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['posts'],
  }
</script>
```

Here's the parent component's parent component, as the component above is nested, yet again, under another component, here's how it passes its post array down;

```
<template>
  <div>
    <user-post-section :posts="friendposts"</user-post-section>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['friendposts'],
  }
</script>
```

Here's the actual view file that creates the array;

```
<dashboard friendposts="[@foreach ($profiledata['friendposts'] as $friendpost)@foreach($friendpost as $post){imageSrc:'/storage/post_images/{{$post->picture_link}}',id:'{{$post->id}}',caption:'{{$post->caption_content}}',location:'{{ucfirst($post->location)}}',href:'/posts/{{$post->id}}',friendName:'{{$post->poster_username}}',friendImgSrc:'/storage/profile_images/{{$post->post_user_profile_picture}}'},@endforeach @endforeach]"></dashboard>
```

Here's how the posts property looks in Vue inspect on browser;

```js
posts: "[
    {
        "imageSrc": "/storage/post_images/5823896B-7980-4BBA-BB5B-E9623D194B22_1579753908.jpeg",
        "id": "11",
        "caption": "Caption",
        "location": "Location",
        "href": "/posts/11",
        "friendName": "test",
        "friendImgSrc": "/storage/profile_images/IMG-0030 (1)_1583849211_1583851620.JPG"
    },
    {
        "imageSrc": "/storage/post_images/29985A50-E78F-42EF-B2FF-2D426B9D4FF0_1583024890.jpeg",
        "id": "17",
        "caption": "Caption2",
        "location": "Location2",
        "href": "/posts/17",
        "friendName": "Testt",
        "friendImgSrc": "/storage/profile_images/Rising-Sun-Circle-Jdm-Japanese-Vinyl-Decal-Sticker_1583024753.jpg"
    },
    {
        "imageSrc": "/storage/post_images/28E01285-70C9-41CF-921C-C7E4DC8D946B_1581958302.jpeg",
        "id": "14",
        "caption": "Caption3",
        "location": "Location3",
        "href": "/posts/14",
        "friendName": "Testt",
        "friendImgSrc": "/storage/profile_images/Rising-Sun-Circle-Jdm-Japanese-Vinyl-Decal-Sticker_1583024753.jpg"
    },
    {
        "imageSrc": "/storage/post_images/2001_1585774742.png",
        "id": "21",
        "caption": "Caption4",
        "location": "Location4",
        "href": "/posts/21",
        "friendName": "Walker",
        "friendImgSrc": "/storage/profile_images/blank.jpg"
    }
]"
```

Sorry to include such a spaghetti arrangement of JSON code, but the point is to show that the object used to build the array of components is correctly formatted, as I would've expected because I've utilized both of these components before, and they worked as intended, but now I've nested it inside another component which passes the data down and now it doesn't work.

Here's the property field for the child component

```
props: ['href', 'imageSrc', 'id', 'caption', 'location', 'friendImgSrc', 'friendName'],
```

I honestly have no clue what's going on, as both components were fully functional on their own, but now when nested it no longer works, even though as far as I can tell by the Vue documentation everything is formatted correctly.

Comment: can you add your parent and child components code?

Comment: I can, but I don't see the relevance, I provided all of the code that connects the two components. What does providing the styling for its container help with? The child component's properties are undefined, so its styling doesn't matter. I'll add the parent's parent code, at least the relevant part.

Comment: yeah just the part where you receive the posts and pass into the children, your current code looks fine from my perspective

Comment: one thing is that your posts json you added in your question is surrounded with `"` which means a string, maybe you just copied the string response from browser and it is actually an objects array in your component?

Comment: would you mind to put console.log when you component is mounted? `export default {
 props: ['friendposts'],
 mounted () {
  console.log(this.friendposts);
 },
}`

Comment: Added code above, return in console is the same JSON as I provided, object is passed down at least to the user-post-section component properly.

Comment: Ok so it's really a json array .. weird thing then.

Comment: Yeah, I don't exactly have a clue what's going on. I have used both of these components previously, except without being nested inside of any other component, and they worked correctly, now, inside of another component, they don't. Thoroughly peculiar.

Comment: Figured out the answer, reference my answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, and of course, the simple answer is always the correct one. Turns out (as I'll now have to search through the documentation to uncover) there is a large importance on the usage of colons for property passage. I had the page written as such:

```
<dashboard friendposts="[insert array of posts here]"></dashboard>
```

When it had to be written like this:

```
<dashboard :friendposts="[insert array of posts here]"></dashboard>
```

I had been getting pretty nonchalant about passing properties to components interchangeably with :property, property, and v-bind:property, as it never seemed to matter. Obviously it does. Hope this helped

Comment: Yeah, kind of embarrassing, going to have to read up on the differences between the different methods of passage. Simplest explanation is usually the right one.

Comment: you have to add `:` for passing a variable, and omit for passing static text

Answer (score -1):

v-for directive use `in` and not `of` reserved word

Comment: This is incorrect, Vue documentation states either are interchangeable. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

Comment: you mean `v-for="(post, index) of posts"` is correct and `v-for="(post, index) in posts"` is incorrect?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo, `in` and `of` are both correct syntax for `v-for`